# How to add Font Awesome to Vue and Nuxt.js project?

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs

I was trying like add as following..

> css: [
> '@/assets/front_end/fontawesome-free-5.15.3-web/css/fontawesome.css'
> ],

But it showing as image like
[image]

Comment: How you are using it in component?

Comment: Have you tried like `css: [ { src:  '~/assets/front_end/fontawesome-free-5.15.3-web/css/fontawesome.css', lang: 'css' } ]` ?

Comment: Yes using it in component but not working, also not working in your way too.

Answer (score 4):

First add the dependency to your project using npm

```
npm i @nuxtjs/fontawesome
```

or if you are using yarn

```
yarn add @nuxtjs/fontawesome
```

then add this to your nuxt.config.js file under buildModules

```
buildModules:['@nuxtjs/fontawesome']
```

Next inside the nuxt.config file add an option for configuring fontawesome. Stating the icons you want to use. For my case I usually add these below

```
fontawesome: {
 icons:{
  solid:true,
  brands:true
 }
}
```

and now you are ready to use your icons in any nuxt component or page
use it like this

```
<font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'home']"/>
```

that's all.

Comment: That would be "npm install" instead of "npm import", right?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. Thank you, I have corrected.

Comment: if you want using light icons , how to process ?

Answer (score 3):

you can import the css from cdn/local in your component / layout

```html
<style scoped>
@import 'https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css';
// or 
@import '@/assets/front_end/fontawesome-free-5.15.3-web/css/fontawesome.css';
</style>
```

or you in you nuxt.config.js ([documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/assets#styles))

```js
export default {
  css: [
    '~/assets/front_end/fontawesome-free-5.15.3-web/css/fontawesome.css'
  ]
}
```

i would suggest using [@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome) you can take advantage of the tree shaking

Comment: Its not working for me with your provided way. and why I use vue-fontawsome? I have found nuxtjs/fontawesome here how can I use nuxtjs/fontawsome?

Comment: you need to be more specific ```not working``` is not clear. as for ```nuxtjs/fontawesome``` this is a separate question you have to refer to the documentation for the package

Comment: Dear sir, Not working means I tried fontawsome both ways individually import into component style and nuxt.config.js but same problem showing.

Comment: check this sandbox i imported the css in the style tag and then added the ```i``` element and works just fine https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-stallman-k0w4d

Comment: if you import the css file locally check if the font is loaded ( using developer tools in your browser ) check the network tab and look for the fontawesome font

Answer (score 1):

You could globally load the script dependency from the head or body (before body end tag), in your `nuxt.config.js` file. Example:

```
export default {
  head: {
    ...
    script: [{src: 'https://kit.fontawesome.com/[user].js', async: true, crossorigin: 'anonymous'},]
  },
```

The above will generate in your HTML:

```
<head>    
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/[user].js" async crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

In the same way for CSS:

```
export default {
  head: {
    ...
    link: [{rel:"stylesheet", href:"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"},]
  },
```

For version 5 of the library, it asks you to register with a user, so the link it generates to load it, contains the user you created ([user]).

> Note: be careful which version you use, because a class you are calling may not exist in the version you load.